# What happens in C if you don't use \0 at the end of a string?

Tags: c

so I know that in C, that '\0' is the null character, used to terminate strings. I've been looking online to see what it actually does, and I've run programs with and without it in my strings to see the difference in its use and non-use. I can't find any.

What can I not do when my strings lack the '\0' character?

Code that worked for me without a \0:

```
char a[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
int x = strlen(a);
char b[10] = {'h','i','j','k','l'};
int y = strcmp(a,b);
printf("%d\n",x);
printf("%d\n",y);
```

Comment: Can you show examples of your code that works both with and without `\0`?

Comment: If your string does not have explicit `\0` then essentially you would also get any garbage after until a memory byte happen to be '\0'. If the memory does not belong to your process, you will get an access violation. **Don't do it**.

Comment: What happens if a train doesn't stop when it meets a bumper at the end of a track?

Comment: Technically, if there's no null terminator then it's not a string.

Comment: You won't be able to call any library functions that require null terminated strings and expect a valid result.

Answer (score 6):

According to the standard (C11 §7.1.1), if it doesn't end with a null byte it is not technically a 'string', it is simply a char array. (Make no mistake c-strings are char arrays as well, but they end in a terminator.)

You won't be able to use many of the string functions `strcat`, `strcmp`, `strcpy`, `strlen`, `printf`, etc, without a lot of your own built-in safeguards. Note, you can perform similar operations if you keep track of the length of the string manually and use functions like `memcpy`, `strnlen`, `sprintf`, etc, but you aren't technically working with c-string when doing so, you're simply working with arrays.

Comment: I put in  char a[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
 int x = strlen(a);
 printf("%d\n",x); without a \0 and it worked fine. So did strcmp.

Comment: @AviG You defined an array of 10 `char` but didn't provide 10 values in the list of initializers. The remaining array elements will be zero initialized. That's why it worked, you got lucky. If you had given 10 values then it would not have a null terminator.